# Overlap Buttons on a Xaml Grid on Powershell with onclick button

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, button, grid

New to Powershell, Xaml and coding in general.

Thanks to StackOverflow, I've build a Grid in Powershell with 10 Columns and 8 Rows and fill it with 80 Buttons (From 1 to 80). Each button will trigger an action.
Now, I would like to have the chance to Click on 1 of these buttons and overlap new buttons (or a whole new Grid) on top of the principal Grid in orther to have more buttons available (From 81 to 160).

To make a clear example:
Let's imagine I'm building an App to make orders in the restaurant.
Grid 1 Show 80 buttons.
If I press the "Main Course" button, it will overlay the 80 buttons containing the 80 differents "Main Course". The same if I press "Dessert" buttons ect.

I understood to use the expression Panel.ZIndex="n" and actually work if I code it in Powershell.

```
<Button Name="Cell2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Opacity="1" Background="#eae0f5" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="UP" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
<Button Name="Cell81" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Opacity="1" Background="#dfd1f0" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="DOWN" Panel.ZIndex="0"/>
```

But when I want to trigger it with a click button like so:

```
$WPFCell1.add_Click({$WPFCell81.Panel.ZIndex ="2"})
```

it returns with the following error:

```
The property 'ZIndex' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:149 char:22
+ $WPFCell1.add_Click({$WPFCell81.Panel.ZIndex ="2"})
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Where should I add the Porperty ZIndex if this is the error?
I know probably there are different way to setup this things, but I would like to find a way to make it happen with this code couse again, I'm a noob, and I'm working with a Library that work with this kind of code.

Many thanks to all of you!

This is the whole code if can halp:

```
#MultiView click overlay
$inputXML = @"
<Window 
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
 x:Name="Window" 
  WindowStyle = "None" WindowState="Maximized"
 ResizeMode = "NoResize" Title = "overlay" AllowsTransparency = "True" Background = "Transparent" Opacity = "1" Topmost = "True">
  <Grid x:Name = "Grid" Background = "Transparent" ShowGridLines="False">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="96" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="96" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="55" />
    <RowDefinition Height="190" />
    <RowDefinition Height="190" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="55" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
<Button Name="Cell1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Opacity="1" Background="#eae0f5" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="MENU"/>
<Button Name="Cell2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Opacity="1" Background="#dfd1f0" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="UP" Panel.ZIndex ="1"/>
<Button Name="Cell3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Opacity="1" Background="#d4c1eb" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="3"/>
<Button Name="Cell4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"  Opacity="1" Background="#c9b2e6" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="4"/>
<Button Name="Cell5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"  Opacity="1" Background="#bfa3e1" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="4"/>
<Button Name="Cell6" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Opacity="1" Background="#b493dc" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="5"/>
<Button Name="Cell7" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6"  Opacity="1" Background="#a984d7" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="6"/>
<Button Name="Cell8" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7"  Opacity="1" Background="#9f74d2" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="7"/>
<Button Name="Cell9" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="8"  Opacity="1" Background="#9465cd" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="8"/>
<Button Name="Cell10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="9"  Background="#f75590" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="9" />
<Button Name="Cell11" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Opacity="1" Background="#dfd1f0" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="10"/>
<Button Name="Cell12" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell13" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell14" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"  Opacity="1" Background="#8956c8" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="14"/>
<Button Name="Cell16" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5"   Opacity="1" Background="Yellow" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="15"/>
<Button Name="Cell17" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell18" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell19" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="8"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="9" Opacity="1" Background="#8956c8" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="20"/>
<Button Name="Cell21" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Opacity="1" Background="#cae916" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="28" Foreground="White" Content="21"/>
<Button Name="Cell22" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell23" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell24" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell25" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell26" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell27" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell28" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="7"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell29" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="8" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell30" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="9"  Opacity="1" Background="#cae916" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="28" Foreground="White" Content="30"/>
<Button Name="Cell31" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  Opacity="1" Background="#c9b2e6" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Content="31"/>
<Button Name="Cell32" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell33" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell34" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell35" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell36" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell37" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="6"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell38" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="7" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell39" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="8"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell40" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="9" Opacity="1" Background="#6a37a9" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Content="40"/>
<Button Name="Cell41" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"  Opacity="1" Background="#bfa3e1" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Content="41"/>
<Button Name="Cell42" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell43" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell44" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell45" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell46" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell47" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="6"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell48" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="7"  Opacity="0.25" Background="#0000ffff" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" Content="48"/>
<Button Name="Cell49" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="8"  Opacity="0.25" Background="#0000ffff" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" Content="49"/>
<Button Name="Cell50" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="9" Opacity="1" Background="#61329a" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="50"/>
<Button Name="Cell51" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"  Opacity="1" Background="#b493dc" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Content="51"/>
<Button Name="Cell52" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell53" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell54" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell55" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell56" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="5" Opacity="1" Background="#a984d7" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="28" Foreground="White" Content="56"/>
<Button Name="Cell57" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="6"  Opacity="1" Background="#9f74d2" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="57"/>
<Button Name="Cell58" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="7"  Opacity="1" Background="#cae916" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="35" Foreground="White" Content="58"/>
<Button Name="Cell59" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="8"  Opacity="1" Background="#f75590" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Content="59"/>
<Button Name="Cell60" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="9" Opacity="1" Background="#4d287b" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" Content="60"/>
<Button Name="Cell61" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"   Opacity="1" Background="#cae916" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="60" Foreground="White" Content="61"/>
<Button Name="Cell62" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell63" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell64" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3" Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell65" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="4"  Opacity="0.01"/>
<Button Name="Cell66" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="5" Opacity="1" Background="#bfa3e1" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="66"/>
<Button Name="Cell67" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="6"  Opacity="1" Background="#a984d7" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="67"/>
<Button Name="Cell68" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="7"  Opacity="1" Background="#9465cd" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="68"/>
<Button Name="Cell69" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="8"  Opacity="1" Background="#a984d7" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Content="69"/>
<Button Name="Cell70" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="9"  Opacity="1" Background="#cae916" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="45" Foreground="White" Content="70"/>
<Button Name="Cell71" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"  Opacity="1" Background="#9f74d2" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="71"/>
<Button Name="Cell72" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"   Opacity="1" Background="#9465cd" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="72"/>
<Button Name="Cell73" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2"   Opacity="1" Background="#8956c8" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="73"/>
<Button Name="Cell74" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3"  Opacity="1" Background="#773dbd" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="74"/>
<Button Name="Cell75" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="4"   Opacity="1" Background="#6a37a9" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="75"/>
<Button Name="Cell76" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="5"  Opacity="1" Background="#61329a" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="76"/>
<Button Name="Cell77" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="6"   Opacity="1" Background="#4d287b" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="77"/>
<Button Name="Cell78" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="7"   Opacity="1" Background="#44236c" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="78"/>
<Button Name="Cell79" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="8"   Opacity="1" Background="#3a1e5c" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="79"/>
<Button Name="Cell80" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="9"  Opacity="1" Background="#30194d" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="80"/>
<Button Name="Cell81" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Opacity="1" Background="#8956c8" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Content="DOWN" Panel.ZIndex ="0"/>


</Grid>
</Window>
"@
$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML
#Read XAML

    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
  try{$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
    Write-Warning "We ran into a problem with the XAML code.  Check the syntax for this control..."
    write-host $error[0].Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
    if ($error[0].Exception.Message -like "*button*"){
        write-warning "Ensure your &lt;button in the `$inputXML does NOT have a Click=ButtonClick property.  PS can't handle this`n`n`n`n"}
}
catch{#if it broke some other way :D
    Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Double-check syntax and ensure .net is installed."
        }


# Create PowerShell object for each WPF button
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name)}

# Map multiview window click to actual
function buttonclicked($btnNAme){
 write-host $btnNAme
 switch($btnNAme){
     0{$Script:Window.close();break
     }
    }
  }   

$WPFCell1.add_Click({$WPFCell16.Panel.ZIndex ="1"})


# Turn on WPF overlay display
$Window.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a workaround to get the same results with .Visibility "Hidden" or "Visible".
Same structure, same use of Panel.Zindex="n" but instead of modifying the ZIndex value with the button, I hide or show the layer on top.
But I'm sure there is a more convinient way to act, so if you have the solution, pleaseeee :).

Cheers,
M